# How can I calculate aggregated means according to three variables

Tags: r, aggregation

I want to calculate the mean value for a continous variable `pwr` according to categorized two-dimensional subgroups in a data frame with categorized age in the columns and categorized weight in the rows according to sex, i.e. mean_pwr=1310 for sex=male & age 20-24 & weight 60-61
mean_pwr=1330 for sex=male & age 20-24 & weight 62-63
...
mean_pwr=654 for sex=female & age 40-44 & weight 68-69

male:

| ------ | 20-25 | 25-29 | 30-34 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60-61 | 1310 | 1234 | 23434 | ... |
| 62-63 | 1330 | 3434 | 4545 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can I do this?

Here is an example data set

```
age <- seq(20, 65, 1)
weight <- seq(60, 110, 1)
sex <- c("male", "female")
d <- expand.grid(age=age, weight=weight, sex=sex)

d$pwr <- runif(nrow(d), min=100, max=1000)
head(d)

d$age_cut <- cut(d$age, 9)
d$weight_cut <- cut(d$weight, 25)

table(d$age_cut)
table(d$weight_cut)
```

Comment: There are tons of ways. One: `tapply(d$pwr, d[,c("age_cut","weight_cut","sex")],mean)`. Another: `aggregate(pwr ~ weight_cut + sex + age_cut, data = d, FUN=mean)`.

Comment: Of course, both `data.table` and `dplyr` offer their variants.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. `ddply(d, c("weight_cut", "age_cut"), summarise,
      mean = round(mean(pwr)))` looks good but how can I transform the data frame to `age_cut` as column headlines and `weight_cut` to row headlines?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
l <- split(d, sex)
# female 
with(l[[1L]], tapply(pwr, list(weight_cut, age_cut), FUN = mean))
# male 
with(l[[2L]], tapply(pwr, list(weight_cut, age_cut), FUN = mean))
```